# exploring google maps API for android

Tags: android, google-maps

Iam developing an android app.about google maps API for android i want to ask that

i have override ontap method so that i'll be getting coordinates of the tapped location on googlemap but know i want to show a marker or pin on the taaped location coordinates. please tell me how i can modify my below code:

```
public boolean onTap(GeoPoint point, MapView mapView) 
       {
         Context contexto = mapView.getContext();
         String msg = "Lat: " + point.getLatitudeE6()/1E6 + " - " + 
                      "Lon: " + point.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;

         Toast toast = Toast.makeText(contexto, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
         toast.show();
        return true;
       }
```

Best Regards,
Muhammad Tahir Ashraf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Answers below.

1. Yes
2. Yes
3. Yes

Every thing is possible.

Check the below link for complete information about the Google Maps.

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Comment: thanks! for the reply i have already made the google map app by following the same link as you provided. but i dnt know how to the above mentioned tasks.Please let me know if you can help me and tell how to do this

Comment: Did u check the Part 2: Adding Overlay Items ?

Comment: Do u want to keep icon which displays on the map ? or whenever we click on a specific point there will be a Dialog ? on that dialog ?

Comment: i want that whenever we click on a specific point an icon gets created on that point on map